# Why does my GtkTreeView update fire only after the gtkitem event finishes?

Tags: gtk, delay, popupmenu, gtktreeview

I have a gtktree with columns and values. I also have a popupmenu with one gtkmenuitem: 'Refresh'.

The refresh event does two things:

- repopulate my gtktree
- preforms a query.

The query is not immediate, it takes about 5 seconds. Why I can see the update of the tree only after the 5 seconds of the query? I want an immediate update of the gtktree, I don't understand the delay of the update.

Comment: I've merged your two accounts together. [Please read this Faq entry about cookie-based accounts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account/1228) Also, StackOverflow isn't a forum; if you have a new question, please ask a new question. If you want to include more information in your question, please [edit it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7476705/edit). If you want to interact with one of the people who has answered, you can leave them a comment.  Also, I think you should read [faq#howtoask] and [faq#bounty].

Comment: Also, I don't code GTK, but I'd bet you are blocking the UI thread.  You need to perform your query on a different thread so that the UI thread can update the tree.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing a long computation, then the program is busy with that and doesn't have time to update the GUI. To solve this problem, make sure that you execute the following code in the "main loop" of your query (if it has such a thing):

```
while(gtk_events_pending())
    gtk_main_iteration();
```

If your query doesn't have a loop, for example if it runs completely in an external library, you will have to do as Will suggests and run it in a separate thread.

Comment: And if your query runs against sqlite, put the above in your sqlite3_progress_handler() callback.